# Text Align justify is not working properly with Arabic characters in iOS

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-stylesheet, react-native-text

1. I wanted to render some Arabic content. When the text is justified ( `textAlign:'justify'` ), the Arabic text is getting hidden both in android and ios.
2. In iOS, the symbols are wrongly aligned when justified using `textAlign:'justify'` (Check the below image for clarification).
3. No issue when `'center','right','left'`.

[image: In iOS the symbols are wrongly aligned]